# ConfigMap value as input for another variable inside container

Tags: kubernetes, nested, environment-variables, containers, configmap

How to use ConfigMap for `$LOCAL_IP_DB` variable declared in below section as input for another variable declared?  `$LOCAL_IP_DB` is a generic key defined inside `db-secret configmap`, but there is another environment variable which needs it? How to make it work?

```
spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: LOCAL_IP_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                    name: db-secret
                    key: LOCAL_IP_DB
            - name: LOG_Files
              value: \\${LOCAL_IP_DB}\redis\files\
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is using: `$()` instead of `${}`

example-pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: example
    image: bash
    args: [printenv]
    env:
    - name: LOCAL_IP_DB
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: db-secret
          key: LOCAL_IP_DB
    - name: LOG_FILES
      value: \$(LOCAL_IP_DB)\redis\files\
```

example-configmap.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  LOCAL_IP_DB: 192.168.0.1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-secret
```

test:

```
controlplane $ kubectl apply -f example-pod.yaml -f example-configmap.yaml 
controlplane $ kubectl logs example | grep 192
LOCAL_IP_DB=192.168.0.1
LOG_FILES=\192.168.0.1\redis\files\
```

You can find more information about this function here: [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config)

Note, if you want to manage secrets [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) is the recommended way to do that.